# Backspace key is not working for lightning-input type="date" field in service console

Tags: lightning-web-components, service-cloud-console, lightning-inputfield

We have created lightning web component and embedded to visualforce page using lightning-out, this VF page we are using in service console app.

If we preview VF page other than console app, then backspace for lightning-input fields are working as expected. But when we open VF page in service console then backspace is not working for lightning-input type="date".

We found that issue is get resolved already by Salesforce, but we are still facing issue.
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008oHOQAY&title=backspace-is-not-working-in-service-console-for-lightning-inputrichtext-contained-inside-a-visualforce-pagehttps://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMf0QAG&title=spring-19-keystrokes-within-lightning-input-component-are-detected-as-hotkeys-in-classic-console.

If anyone have any solution or any approach will help us lot.